# android-studio how to set xml theme

Tags: android, xml

I am using android-studio..

I am creating **activity.xml** file..There from the **themes** I choose a **Light.NoTitlebar** in graphical view.

And then when I run that app..It is showing the default which is in **styles.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

And my **Manifestfile.xml** is

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

How can I change the xml theme whatever I want??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a custom theme,

`res/values/themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

And then apply this theme to any activity you want to. Just add `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"` attribute to `<activity>` tag of `manifest` file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="activity_title"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to **styles.xml** file and add the following to it. That's it.Easy as follows

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!--Add your custom theme here -->
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

You can create any number of custom styles and apply it in the **manifestfile.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"></activity>
```